# How to configure PM2 to start certain applications based on the system's environment variables?

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, pm2

I went through the PM2 documentation and it looks like it provides the facility to send environment variables to your application but I could not find any information on how to configure PM2 such that it starts applications based on the system's environment variables.

For example, I have the following config file -

```
module.exports = {
    apps: [{
        name: 'app',
        script: 'app.js',
        instances: 1,
        autorestart: true,
        watch: true
    }, {
        name: 'worker',
        script: './server/sync.js',
        instances: 1,
        autorestart: true,
        watch: true
    }]
};
```

On the server where I have an environment variable set, say `database`, I want the `worker` app to run. Otherwise, I want the main application `app` to run.

I basically want to run `pm2 start ecosystem.config.js` and let PM2 decide which of the applications to start based on the system's environment variables. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Is this on unix/Linux or Windows?

Comment: This is on Linux, specifically CentOS 7.2.